# How to specify columns to exclude when retaining all distinct rows?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

How do you retain all distinct rows in a data frame excluding certain columns by specifying only the columns you want to exclude. In the example below

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- data_frame(
    x = c("a", "a", "b"),
    y = c("c", "c", "d"),
    z = c("e", "f", "f")
)
```

I'd like to return a data frame with all distinct rows among variables `x` and `y` by only specifying that I'd like to exclude column `z`. The data frame returned should look like the data frame returned from here

```
dat %>% distinct(x, y)
```

You would think you can do the following, but it results in an error

```
dat %>% distinct(-z)
```

I prefer a tidyverse solution

Comment: So maybe do `select(-z)` first?

Comment: What's wrong with `unique(dat[1:2])`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just do:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  distinct_at(vars(-z))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  x     y    
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     c    
2 b     d
```

And as of `dplyr` 1.0.0, you can use `across`:

```
dat %>% 
  distinct(across(-z))
```

Comment: `distinct_at()` will be superseded by use of `across()` inside `distinct()` from version 1.0.0 (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#across). The equivalent pattern for your answer would be `dat %>% distinct(across(-z))` but `distinct_at()` will still be available for several years.

Answer (score 2):

We could use

```
dat %>% 
    distinct(!!! rlang::syms(setdiff(names(.), "z")))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  x     y    
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 a     c    
#2 b     d
```